# How to select all rows which have identical values

Tags: mysql

Here is my table:

```
+----+-------+------+
| id | name  | code |
+----+-------+------+
| 1  | jack  | 1    |
| 2  | peter | 1    |
| 3  | jack  | 1    |
| 4  | ali   | 2    |
| 5  | peter | 3    |
| 6  | peter | 1    |
| 7  | ali   | 2    |
| 8  | jack  | 3    |
| 9  | peter | 2    |
| 10 | peter | 4    |
+----+-------+------+
```

I want to select all rows that satisfy: the number of {those rows which its `code` value is between 1-3 and its `name` vale is identical} be more or equal than 4

From the above data, I want this output:

```
+----+-------+------+
| id | name  | code |
+----+-------+------+
| 2  | peter | 1    |
| 5  | peter | 3    |
| 6  | peter | 1    |
| 9  | peter | 2    |
+----+-------+------+
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a subquery to figure out which names should be returned, then build your main query on that.

Try this:

```
select *
from mytable
where name in (
    select name
    from mytable
    where code between 1 and 3
    group by name
    having count(*) > 3)
and code between 1 and 3
```

Comment: Look, In reality the range is more that just three numbers `1`, `2`, `3`. So may you please use `between ... and ...` instead of `in()` in your query?